# Порядок выполнения команд на ASP-странице

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, javascript

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, чтобы сначала выполнялись команды на языке C# (код страницы в обработчике, например), после этого выполнялся `JavaScript`, а после этого - опять команды на языке C#. Схематично так :

```
asp-команда 1; 
asp-команда 2;
asp-команда 3; 
javascript 
asp-команда 4; 
asp-команда 5;
```

Если написать код так, как я тут указал, то получается, что выполнятся асп-команды 1-5, и после этого только javascript. Я просто хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователю появлялось confirm-сообщение, и по нажатию на кнопку "ОК" выполнялись команды 4-5, а на "Отмена" - не выполнялись.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении  копать!

Comment: можно, если пункты 4-5 вывести в ajax.

Comment: дело в том, что в пунктах 4-5 находится код удаления записи из БД. можно такое  сделать в аяксе?

Comment: в аяксе можно сделать запрос на сервер. А уже на сервере  можно сделать что-нибудь с БД

Comment: я кажется начинаю пониматься аякс. Посоветуйте статейку с примером, или книгу хорошу, пожалуйста. задача срочная стоит,  а с аяксом я раньше не работал.

Comment: @chudo116 уж потрудитесь погуглить. И вообще, если вы пишете на ASP.NET (не MVC) то вы уверены, что вам нужен именно AJAX и непосредственная работа с JavaScript'ом? Событийная модель ASP.NET способна покрыть большинство потребностей при общении клиента с сервером

Comment: гуглить - не перегуглить:)  вопрос был в том, что инфы много, и она излагается не последовательно и рывками, а хороших источников я не нашел. Так что вопрос мой имеет право на жизнь.  Я затеял работу со скриптами только потому, что мне нужно получить диалоговое окно у клиента  с кнопками, и пользователь что-то выбрать должен, и от этого выбора зависит дальнейшее поведение страницы (более конкретно: удалить строку из таблицы или нет ). Может, это можно без скрипта сделать, силами только ASP? Спасибо за всем реакции!

Comment: у вас ASP.NET или ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: использую ASP.NET

Comment: тогда посмотрите в сторону Ajax Toolkit. При правильной работе с ним даже не придется использовать JS напрямую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, с помощью jQuery:

```
  $('object_id').dialog({
      modal: true, 
      title: 'dialog_name', 
      zIndex: 1000, 
      autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto', 
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
      Yes: function () {
          $.getJSON("action_for_yes" { Data: your_data }, function(data) {
               //....
          });
          $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      No: function () {
          $.getJSON("action_for_no" { Data: your_data }, function(data) {
               //....
          });
          $(this).dialog("close");
      }
  },
  close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).remove();
  }
```

Comment: Интересный код, спасибо. 
А можно аяксом получить кол-во строк в DataGrid'e на форме?
В ASP так получается: DataGrid.Items.Count; Можно тут что-то такое сделать?

Comment: var rowsCount = <%=GridView1.Rows.Count %>

Comment: вот что мне не нравится в молодых кодерах ASP и Java - они никак не могут понять разницу между кодом выполняемым на сервере и на клиенте.

Comment: думаю, это свойственно любому языку, позволяющему писать клиент-серверные приложения

Comment: неа, мне кажется это из-за того что

>  Событийная модель ASP.NET способна покрыть большинство потребностей при общении клиента с сервером

т.е. человек не отдает себе отчет, когда он пишет серверную, а когда клиентскую часть, думаю с nodejs тож самое будет, если не хуже.

Comment: ASP.NET (тот, что WebForms, a не MVC) вообще не самое лучшее решение в этом плане. Попытка сделать web "как десктоп" в чем-то не лишена  смысла, но все же способна привести к таким заблуждениям. Но дело тут не только и не столько в этом. Для совсем-совсем начинающего разработчика клиент и сервер обычно сосредоточены в рамках одной машины, поэтому он долго не может заметить разницу между ними. А еще иногда тому виной переход с разработки под десктоп на веб.

Comment: @eicto кстати в отличие от node.js в ASP.NET клиент за некоторыми исключениями не пишется на том же языке, что и сервер

Comment: скорее в переходе на программирование в сети. а не в веб.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, на сервере:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "funcJsName", "try{jscode} catch(ex){}", true);
```

но там свои нюансы есть, вроде они параллельно после js кода пойдут